# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[] SQLDriverConnect: 0 (80% of the time it does work)

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc, wampserver

**Information**

One of my customers was using the following *setup* for their webapplication:

1. IIS: via IP (not url) by default port 80;
2. PHP v5.3 (and yes the company that helped them went for PHP with IIS);
3. Access as database (data.accdb), version Microsoft 364 for companies;
4. ODBC as a connection between PHP and the Access database. To make this available Microsoft Access database engine 2016 (English), version 16.0.5044.1000 was installed;

This customer mostly works with a custom made (frontend) application in Access (app.accdb) that works with the data.accdb for data. Beside that they need the webapplication for managing some of the data by employees of them that are on the road a lot (and are not always able to take over the server and work with the Access application).

**The Problem**

A couple of weeks back there was an Microsoft-365 update (v16.0.13231.20262) and apparently they had automatic updates still enabled. From the moment the update was done the ODBC connection wasn't working anymore.

After trying a lot of stuff I decided to change IIS to WampServer to see if that changed anything (it was a better setup than with IIS). The webapplication was working again but from time to time we got the following error by PHP:

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[] SQLDriverConnect: 0 in *.php on line 13`
`PDOException: SQLSTATE[] SQLDriverConnect: 0 in *.php on line 13`

Line 13 in that PHP file is:

`$this->con = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" . DATABASE_PATH);`

Obviously the path is working cause like 80% of the time the webapplication is working fine. From time to time *it*  just gets stuck. When I restart the services of WampServer it all works fine again.

**What have I tried**

From this point on I started looking for possible problems by looking at Event Viewer and logs (access.log, apache_error.log, php_error.log) and I came to the following list:

1. Attacks from bots

For the attacks from bots we got requests like this:

`AH02811: script not found or unable to stat`

At first I tried to *Deny from IP* to make sure they couldn't be the problem but there were so many IP addresses it didn't fix anything. I made sure the customer changed to working with an url instead of the IP address of the server. I made WampServer so that the default port 80 was only working via *local*. We obviously still get the requests but it gets denied by the client:

`AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/`

I'm still not a 100% sure I can exclude this from the list of potential problems cause of the timeline of the error with like 10-15 *attacks* before that like I just mentioned.

2. Because the customer is working with the Access application on the same Access database (as the webapplication) I feel like this could be a problem as well.
3. Potentially it could be like the previous one (number 2) but then for multiple requests via the webapplication.

Yesterday I decided to create a timeline with all the logs/events to see if I could see (with multiple error moments) where the problem was coming from. But the timeline doesn't make anything concrete or exclude any of the potential problems. An example of one of the timelines:

```
FRIDAY 9-OCT
11:51:36    Attack
12:01:30    Attack
12:30:09    Attack
13:04:16    Attack
13:21:53    Attack
14:30:31    Attack
14:30:31    Attack
15:52:53    Attack
16:06:15    Requests from IP 1
16:07:34    Requests from IP 2
16:07:53    Requests from IP 3
16:08:10    Error
16:08:21    Error
16:08:24    Error
16:08:30    Error
16:08:34    Error
16:08:35    Error
16:10:37    Restart WampServer
16:10:53    Error
16:15:12    Restart WampServer
```

I'm stuck at this point and just can't seem to find the cause of the problem. I know I could change the ODBC to OleDB but that means I need to rewrite the whole webapplication and that's at the moment just not an option. My expertise is not this setup/PHP so that doesn't help in this matter.

Somewhere I thought going for an other port would maybe exclude the attacks so I could make sure the webserver would not do anything with port 80, but it seems a lot of hassle for a long shot.

Yesterday I created a task that restart WampServer every 3 hours and when there is a specific event (Log:Application, Source:Application Error, Event ID:1000). This seems to work for now, bit combersome, but yeah, I had to do something to make it workable-ish for now.

**Concluding**

It's possible I forgot some of the steps I did and tried in this whole story, cause it was just too much to remember. If there are logs needed of more information I would love to hear it. Thank you in advance for reading this Wall of Text and thinking about or helping with potential solutions!

Comment: [1/2] There's a reason that Microsoft has the following disclaimer: _The Access Database Engine Redistributable is not intended to be used by a system service or server-side program where the code will run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless behavior. Examples would include a program that is run from task scheduler when no user is logged in, or a program called from server-side web application such as ASP.NET, or a distributed component running under COM+ services._

Comment: [2/2] The Access Database Engine is not designed to be used for web applications, no matter if you use PHP or ASP.NET. While you might be able to alleviate issues by forcing your web server to run only single thread to serve all users, only execute database operations synchronously, and never leave a connection open, such an approach is inherently not scaleable and will cause problems.

Comment: Yeah @Erik A, I understand what you mean. Before the Microsoft Update (while they still used IIS) there were like 0 problems tho. Any idea how this is possible or what changed (perhaps with the Access database engine *setup*) that causes this problem then? Cause of course I understand what you're saying, but why wasn't this a problem with the IIS setup still in play?

Comment: Perhaps IIS was not using multiple PHP instances (fastCGI max instances set to 1), that significantly reduces problems since you don't have trouble with multiple connections. Perhaps the service was used less. Perhaps it was used in a different way. No real way to tell.

Comment: @Erik A, the moment I install fastCGI to recreate the same idea which was probably on IIS as well (max instance set to 1) the whole webapplication isn't working anymore (actually exact the same as with IIS when Office got updated). The error is: "Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in". So it actually works 0% of the time instead of 80%. Is there an other solution to make WampServer like it only uses one instance?

Comment: That PDO exception sounds like a 32-64 bit mismatch is very fixable. I don't have experience with WampServer, I'm 99% sure it supports this as it's a basic feature but I don't know how.

Comment: That crossed my mind, but: Office is 32 bits, Database Engine as well, WampServer as well. In the ODBC program I can see the MDB/ACCDB on 32 bits as well. But I can definitely be wrong! My head is spinning from all these 'techniques' that are not my cup of soup and I get allergies from these 'techniques' :-D

I tried Apache MPM as well but unless I messed up the settings that didn't seem the way to go. Or at least, like you already said, database operations need to be synchronously, never leave a connection open and so on (and believe me, this is not an option with this webapplication atm).

Comment: There are 32 and 64 bit versions of WAMPServer, WHICH did you install.